# Upload Image and Video to server using apollo-upload-client in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, graphql, apollo-client

I am using apollo client and server and from the server the image uploads to Cloudinary no problem. but In the app whoever I tried to send the file to the server, it says `createReadStream is not a function, code: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`. I am using image picker dependency of react-native which gives me a file path and other file specs and base64 whether I send the whole file or only the path or base64 it does not work.

the file is not going through correctly

my `apolloConfig.js` is:

```
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink } from "@apollo/client";
import { Observable } from "apollo-link";
import { withClientState } from "apollo-link-state";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";
import { buildAxiosFetch } from "@lifeomic/axios-fetch";
import { Config } from "App/Config";
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const SERVER_URL = Config.API_URL;
const cache = new InMemoryCache({});

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: SERVER_URL,
  credentials: "same-origin",
  fetch: buildAxiosFetch(axios, (config, input, init) => ({
    ...config,
    onUploadProgress: init.onUploadProgress,
  })),
});

const request = async (operation) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log(token);
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  });
};

export const requestLink = new ApolloLink(
  (operation, forward) =>
    new Observable((observer) => {
      let handle;
      Promise.resolve(operation)
        .then((oper) => request(oper))
        .then(() => {
          handle = forward(operation).subscribe({
            next: observer.next.bind(observer),
            error: observer.error.bind(observer),
            complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
          });
        })
        .catch(observer.error.bind(observer));
      return () => {
        if (handle) handle.unsubscribe();
      };
    })
);

const link = ApolloLink.from([
  onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      console.log("[graphQLErrors]", graphQLErrors);

      graphQLErrors.map(({ message, extensions }) => {
        console.log(
          `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, code: ${extensions.code}`
        );
        if (extensions.code === "UNAUTHENTICATED") {
          AsyncStorage.clear();
        }
      });
    }
    if (networkError) {
      console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }
  }),
  requestLink,
  httpLink,
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({ link, cache });

export { client };
```

my uploadAvatar.js

```
try {
        const { data } = await uploadImage({
          variables: { file: image },
        });
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Toast.show({
          type: "error",
          position: "bottom",
          text1: "Authentication Failed",
          text2: "Something went wrong while uploading photo!",
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: That particular error sounds like a server-side issue. That can happen, for example, if you don't `await` the file argument.

Comment: I did not write the server code but It can be uploaded to the server no problem from postman . even it works in a react web app

Comment: @Alirezatk were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @saranshmehra Yes I will put an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your file to a `ReactNativeFile` as the docs of apollo-upload-client mentioned

```
import { ReactNativeFile } from 'apollo-upload-client';

const file = new ReactNativeFile({
  uri: uriFromCameraRoll,
  name: 'a.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
});
```

***more info*** : https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client